# Get social share count for Asian social networks (QZone, Renren & Mixi)

Tags: api, social-networking

I'm trying to get the share counts for any (or all) of the social networking sites QZone, Renren & Mixi. The counts are being fetched server-side so I was hoping for some kind of API but I don't speak Chinese or Japanese so I'm having trouble finding the right information.

Any pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated as my searches so far haven't yielded anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Requests for offsite resources are off-topic for stackoverflow - however a quick look found http://dev.renren.com which is usable via online translation eg google translate and has a full API. The best place to ask would be a developers group for mostly Asia based developers.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do and if you already have functionality to share to those networks or not, if not then many of the third party sharing services provide that and will do the share counting for you eg add this, add to any etc. I understand that some sites based in Asia are restricted by country of origin so signing up for a test account must is restricted to mobiles registried in specific countries, anonymous and open to all it is not.